# python nested while loops and datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.7

I'm teaching myself python to ATBS. Instead of spending 45 minutes typing out a bunch of repetitive data in excel I've spent the past 90 failing to write a simple calendar script.

Starting with the values "2012-09-01" and "2012-09-30" I want to each line to increase the month value by 1 it hits 12 and at which point the year value advances by 1, until the date 2018-12-31.

e.g.

"2012-09-01   2012-09-30
2012-10-01   2012-10-31
2012-11-01   2012-11-30
2012-12-01   2012-12-31"

Here's my code, which stops at 2012-12-31.

```
import datetime

year = 2012
month = 9
day_start = 1
day_end = 31

while year <= 2018:
    while month <= 12:
        if month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11:
            day_end = 30
        else:
            day_end = 31
        print(datetime.date(year, month, day_start), " ", datetime.date(year, month, day_end))
        month = month + 1
year = year + 1
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: 2012-09-01 2012-09-30 2012-10-01 2012-10-31 2012-11-01 2012-11-30 2012-12-01 2012-12-31

Comment: And how do you handle February ?

Comment: have a look at [dateutil's relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) or [pandas' date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html).

Comment: Use the `datetime.timedelta` class.

Comment: I had another If statement nested in their to address that but it gave me an error so I took it out :-) It's next on the list

Comment: You need to indent `year = year + 1` and also reset `month` to 1 every new year

Comment: @AdrianKeister: `timedelta` class does not have a `month`, so I think what the OP wants to do becomes a bit tedious (see e.g. dspr's comment...)

Comment: What's ATBS abbreviation?

Comment: @MrFuppes Yeah, you're right. Seems like that would be a very nice addition to `timedelta`. It would make a number of computations like these much more straight-forward.

Comment: ATBS = Automate the Boring Stuff

Comment: The easy way to do this is with [calendar.monthrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) from the stdlib, which gives you the number of days in a month, for any given year/month. This automatically handles leap years, so all you need is a couple of for-loops to iterate over the years and months and no other calculations are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Using the `calendar` library to detect leap years.

```
import datetime
import calendar

year = 2012
month = 9
day_start = 1
day_end = 31

while year <= 2018:
    while month <= 12:
        if month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11:
            day_end = 30
        elif month == 2:
            day_end = 29 if calendar.isleap(year) else 28
        else:
            day_end = 31
        print(datetime.date(year, month, day_start), " ", datetime.date(year, month, day_end))
        month = month + 1
    year = year + 1
    month = 1
```

Line

```
if month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11:
```

can be abbreviated to:

```
if month in (4, 6, 9, 11):
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the suggestions above about timedelta etc, but building upon my existing code is very helpful so I can see WTH is going on.

Comment: When I look at what you wrote, it see why it stopped in it's tracks. I needed to reset the month value to 1 if I wanted it to start again at the next year. Thanks!